# angular2 reuse the view of a component instance

Tags: angular

This is a weird context and question, I know. 
I just want to learn how I should think, what is wrong with such an approach and why.

It's an angular2 arhitectural question in the end.

Let's start.

**Here is the context**:

I have a component Card contained in a component Docker (which holds a list of Cards created in an ngFor loop). 
The main focus is on the Card component. It has some logic and displays a view.

Here is the html template of the parent of docker, showing how docker will be used:

```
<div [hidden]="condition">
   <home></home>
</div>
<div [hidden="!condition"]>
   <docker></docker
</div>
```

It displays `docker` or `home` alternatively.

Now `home` (HomeComponent) wants to display also the same list of `Cards`.

Normally I would add in HomeComponent an ngFor loop to create all the Cards. Again.
I would have the Cards instantiated twice (once for `docker` parent, once for `home` parent). So each Card would have two running instance.

Let's say CardComponent has a complex logic: listening to some events and react by emitting other events.

**And now the weird questions**:

I don't want two instances of the CardComponent to be created (I don't want events processed in double). I want just one instance in DockerComponent. It is possible to reuse it's View (HostView) also in HomeComponent ? So the component code to be run only once, but its view to be placed two times in the resulting html.
And checking for changes (angular mechanism) to result in both views updated.

It's like: I pass the array of CardComponent objects from the DockerComponent (who creates them) to the HomeComponent (via a service), here I extract the view from each CardComponent object and inject it in a ng-container inside HomeComponent.

Alos, having the component object:

- how to access its view ? (not possible ? )
- how to access the ComponentRef ? (this is available only when a component is Dynamically Created, which is not my case)

Now, this scenario is wrong, I feel it.

But I want a debate on what exactly is wrong, how should I think in angular for such cases.

Additionally what are the angular limitations, clearly stated, and the rationale behind them. 
Like you have no access to a component view, nor to it's ComponentRef ( which is really strange: when I the the component object itself I have no access to the ... component reference - here `Ref` is misleading, it's clearly not a normal "reference" term).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something else. Let me explain it.
Instead of show and hide home and docker component in the same page, you could create routeroutlet and depending on path you will show the home or the docker. Both inside can have an ngFor of cards component (or create a "listCardsComponent" if you don't want to repeat ngFor code). This way angular router will handle automatically instance of cards component.

Comment: of course. The problem with using router is that it destroys and recreates the components when switch/navigation occurs. Not acceptable from our use case point of view because the components lose some history when they are fresh created.